# Ant scripting creating 2 class files

Tags: java, ant, jaxb

I am not sure If I am asking a very simple question but I have a project in which the developer has used "XSD" files to create java source codes. The input to the project is an XML message which will be parsed into java object.

The project is working fine if I export the class files into a jar file (using eclipse options to export class files into jar files).

But if I use "ant" script to compile and create a jar file, I always get "JAXBException". After Checking I found that the main java file is compiled into 2 class files by ant script, whereas when I use eclipse to compile there is only one class file.

For example - 
Main Java file - MpgProcessor.java

**Compile using eclipse** - MpgProcessor.class

**Compile using ant**     - MpgProcessor.class and MpgProcessor$1.class.

I am using following command in ant to compile the java files -

```
<target name="compile" depends="clean-build-files" >
    <echo message="STEP 2 = COMPILING JAVA FILES " />
    <mkdir dir="${classDir}" description="Ensure launch directory created" />       
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classDir}" classpathref="build.classpath" debug="on" compiler="javac1.6"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.generated}" destdir="${classDir}" classpathref="build.classpath" debug="on" compiler="javac1.6" verbose="off"/>        
</target>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: the MpgProcessor$1.class is result of some anonymous class created within the code, with construct like new SomeInterface(){/*inline implementation*/}. If this is the case, I would rather ask, why Eclipse is not producing this one...

Comment: Hi Petr Kozelka, you are absolutely right. MpgProcessor does implement one interface. I have no idea why Eclipse is generating single class.

Comment: Wait - `MpgProcessor implements SomeInterface` is not the case; I was really meaning the case with `new` keyword + some interface, somewhere inside class body; you can post some parts of the class to make it clear